# Resizing a video according to a fixed widget in Qt

Tags: qt, video, widget

I designed a form in Qt Creator. I have three controls.

- Group Box (the bottom control)
- Widget    (the middle control)
- Label    (the upper most control)

I show/play the frames of the video on the Label (may be it is not a proper way but I am new to Qt so for the time being it works for me).

My controls are of fixed size.

My question is that How can I resize the video according to my controls (i.e widget or Label)?
I want all the videos to play with the same size as my widget or my label, (both of them have the same size).

To make it clearer, I have two snapshots of my program.

I want the second video (the smaller one ) to play with the same one as the first one. Or if the video is larger than the Widget it must be shrinked to the size of the Label, Kind of a streching and shrinking or something else.

You can see the border of my widget in both the videos.

Any solution will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance

[image: The first video (normal one)]

[image: This is the 2nd video (small in size)]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`myLabel.setScaledContents(true)` should do it.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem in my code. I  was unknowingly resizing the label which I shouldn't have to do that. After removing that line of code I solved my problem.

My code is as follows:

```
 std::string fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Open Video"), ".",tr("Video Files (*.mp4 *.avi)")).toStdString();

 cv::VideoCapture capture(fileName);

 if (!capture.isOpened())
 {
     QMessageBox msgBox;
     msgBox.setWindowTitle("Error");
     msgBox.setIcon(QMessageBox::Critical);
     msgBox.setButtonText(2,"OK");
     msgBox.setText("The video was not loaded!");
     msgBox.exec();
 }

 Mat cur_frame, pre_frame; // current video frame

 capture.read(imgsize);

 cv::Mat out(imgsize.rows,imgsize.cols,CV_8SC1);
 cv::Mat out2(imgsize.rows,imgsize.cols,CV_8SC1);

     Mat cur_frame_gray(imgsize.rows,imgsize.cols,CV_8SC1);

if (!paused) {
         // read next frame if any
         if (!capture.read(cur_frame)) break;

         cvtColor(cur_frame,cur_frame_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);

         QCoreApplication::processEvents();

         //read second frame if any
         if(!capture.read(pre_frame)) break;
         cvtColor(pre_frame,pre_frame_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);

         QCoreApplication::processEvents();

         Mat resizedframe1,resizedframe2,resizedframe3,resizedframe4; // to contain resized image

         cvtColor(cur_frame,cur_frame,CV_BGR2RGB);

        // here I am dividing the rows and columns of the frames by 2 to make them smaller. 
         cv::resize(cur_frame,resizedframe1,cv::Size(cur_frame.cols/2,cur_frame.rows/2));

         IplImage  myFrame=resizedframe4;

        Mat matFrame=&myFrame;

         QImage img1= QImage((const unsigned char*)(resizedframe1.data),resizedframe1.cols,resizedframe1.rows,QImage::Format_RGB888);

         //display on label
         //the label stretches and shrinks according to the frame of the video.

         ui->label->setScaledContents(true);
         ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(img1));

}
// resize the label to fit the image
         // The problem was here, I was resizing the label but I shouldn't have to do it.
         // by removing the following line of code, my problem was solved :)
           ui->label->resize(ui->label->pixmap()->size());

         QCoreApplication::processEvents();

         waitKey(delay);

 }

         // Close the video file
         capture.release();

}
```